# How can I use temp table when creating view?

Tags: mysql, view, temp

MySQL doesn't allow temp table when creating a view, is there any work around for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a permanent table with `ENGINE=MEMORY` as a halfway house. Just remember to truncate it when you are done working with it.